# Deleting linked list nodes without recursion

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list

I have a doubly linked list data structure that looks like the following:

[image]

Node structure is as follows:

```
typedef struct {
    int32_t type;
    int32_t valueint;
    double  valuedouble;
    struct  cNODE *next;
    struct  cNODE *prev;
    struct  cNODE *child;
} cNODE;
```

Each node has a child element which can point to another node/doubly linked list of the same element(node) type. Till now, I used the following code to delete this complete data structure:

```
/* Delete a cNODE structure. */
void cNODE_Delete(cNODE *c)
{
    cNODE*next;
    while (c)
    {
        next=c->next;
        if (!(c->type)) && c->child)
        { 
          cNODE_Delete(c->child)
        };
        free(c);
        c=next;
    }
}
```

But this is a recursive function. I have a certain requirement where I can't use recursion. Can this deletion be implemented without recursion? Any examples are appreciated.

Comment: What is your `cJSON_Delete` function ?

Comment: Any recursion is basically a `while` loop.

Comment: As Eli mentioned above, a recursion is a while loop storing the state information in the stack. Implement that stack in your application and use `while`

Comment: While the marked duplicate is the generic answer to your asked question, I don't believe this particular problem requires a stack to solve.

Comment: @blatinox, sorry it was cNODE_Delete() only. Corrected the post.

Comment: Thanks @jxh. I was not knowing that the question was already there!

Comment: The `if` condition is not well formed.

Comment: I have provided an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38264992/315052

Comment: @jxh, yup admit that, anyway it is just a prototype code.